# I Can't deploy google oauth app in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-oauth

I am deploying google oauth app in heroku.  For that i have to verify app domain to google master but herkou app url is different and google  webmaster is not accepting.  Any way to verify heroku url. https://stormy-sea-79521.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 4):

Definitely! There are a few options to verify ownership of your domain. The recommended method is to add an `html` verification file to your app at https://stormy-sea-79521.herokuapp.com/.

You should be able to add download the file from Google Search Console, then deploy it to the root of your project at, say: https://stormy-sea-79521.herokuapp.com/googlexxxyyyyzzz.html.

There are a few steps to generating the `html` file:

1. Sign into [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console) (fka Google webmaster tools)
2. In the Property menu, click "Add Property",
   [image: Add property menu is in the top right of the GSC]
3. Enter your site URL: "https://stormy-sea-79521.herokuapp.com/"
4. Click "Continue",
5. Download the verification file that Google presents you with, as shown below:
   [image: Download a Google verification file]
6. Keep the Search Console open while you upload this file to your Heroku instance and finally,
7. Click "Verify" in the Search Console.
8. Celebrate!

There are alternative verification methods as well. You could add a specific `meta` tag to your home page, or associate your Google Analytics or Google Tag Manager account. [Find Google's docs for verifying your domain here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080#html_verification).

Comment: @Graerne Thanks a lot for writing back. Since i am a newbie in node . I didn't know to add html meta tag in node app. Just gone through the heroku doc (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs) and solved the issue. :)