# Google OAuth verification of Web App with Heroku

Tags: heroku, google-api

**What I have build:**

- A web application hosted on Heroku which reads coworkers' calendar and generates travel time events in their calendars. This way they can easily see what time they HAVE to leave to be on time for their next appointment.
- I expect that 50 coworkers (at most) will use the web app. The app is not intended or made for external use.
- I am using sensitive scopes (namely event writing permissions), so the web app has to be verified.

**My problem:**

- Verification requires verified ownership of the web app domain, but I have it hosted on Heroku. I received a mail from Google's verification team which mentioned:

> Please Note: Third party domain not owned by you, or domains that are hosted by a third party site, or redirects to third party sites are not permitted.

**My question:**

- Can I use Heroku to pass the verification, or is it simply not allowed to use Heroku for web apps that use Google OAuth?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to this problem: [I Can't deploy google oauth app in heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54231660/i-cant-deploy-google-oauth-app-in-heroku)

I followed the steps and it worked! Google accepts the verification.
Note: in the Search Console, pick the URL prefix option and select the Meta Data verification option. I found that was the easiest to implement.